# query pulling up data in either condition

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

everything is working fine in this code, the only problem that i have that when i click the "today" from drop down and there is no data for today in DB, its still pulling up data, as if its taking value from "txtCity". only when i put something in txtCity something other than what i have in DB it return empty

```
        string strVal = hdnOption.Value;
        IFormatProvider provider = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB", true);
        DateTime dtStart = new DateTime();
        DateTime? dtEnd = null;
        string strCity = null;

        if (strVal == "0")
        {
            HideCustomSearch();
            dtStart = DateTime.Today;
            dtEnd = DateTime.Today;

            if (txtCityName != null)
            {
                strCity = txtCityName.Text.ToString().Trim();
            }
        }
        if (strVal == "today") 
        {
            HideCustomSearch();
            dtStart = DateTime.Today;
            dtEnd = DateTime.Today;
            if (txtCityName != null)
            {
                strCity = txtCityName.Text.ToString().Trim();
            }
        }
        if (strVal == "weekly")
        {
            HideCustomSearch();
            dtStart = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7).Date;
            dtEnd = DateTime.Today;
            strCity = txtCityName.Text.ToString().Trim();
        }
        if (strVal == "byweekly")
        {
            HideCustomSearch();
            dtStart = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-15).Date;
            dtEnd = DateTime.Today;
            strCity = txtCityName.Text.ToString().Trim();
        }
        if (strVal == "monthly")
        {
            HideCustomSearch();
            dtStart = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1).Date;
            dtEnd = DateTime.Today;
            strCity = txtCityName.Text.ToString().Trim();
        }
        if (strVal == "yearly")
        {
            HideCustomSearch();
            dtStart = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1).Date;
            dtEnd = DateTime.Today;
            strCity = txtCityName.Text.ToString().Trim();
        }
        if (strVal == "custom")
        {
            ShowCustomSearch();
            //this.txtdtStart = "22/10/2010";
            //dtStart = DateTime.Parse("07-01-2013", provider,                System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault);
            string d = "07-01-2013";
            dtStart = DateTime.ParseExact(d, "dd-MM-yyyy", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces);
            dtEnd = DateTime.ParseExact(d, "dd-MM-yyyy", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces);
            strCity = txtCityName.Text.ToString().Trim();

            hdndtStart.Value = txtdtStart.ToString();
            hdndtEnd.Value = txtdtEnd.Text.ToString();
        }
        FillGridFilter(dtStart, dtEnd, strCity);
```

P.S. sorry i forgot to add query

```
if @start_date = DAY(getdate()) and @end_date = null and @city = null
    begin
    select jp.id, city.name[City]
    , row_number() over (order by city.name) [sr_no]
    , count(jp.id) over (partition by name) as no_of_posts 
    , COUNT(od.id) over (partition by name) as no_of_employers
    ,CONVERT(varchar(12), jp.posting_date, 103) [date_created]

from rs_job_posting jp

inner join rs_job_posting_location jpl on jpl.id = jp.id
inner join rs_cor_city city on city.id = jpl.city_fk
inner join rs_organization_detail od on od.id = jp.id

where DAY(posting_date) = @start_date
order by no_of_posts Desc
```

END

Comment: which query is pulling data. show us

Comment: Sorry, but without the query itself it's almost impossible to knwow what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
if (@start_date = DAY(getdate()) AND @end_date IS NULL AND @city IS NULL)
  begin
   select jp.id, city.name[City]
        , row_number() over (order by city.name) [sr_no]
        , count(jp.id) over (partition by name) as no_of_posts 
        , COUNT(od.id) over (partition by name) as no_of_employers
        ,CONVERT(varchar(12), jp.posting_date, 103) [date_created]

    from rs_job_posting jp

    inner join rs_job_posting_location jpl on jpl.id = jp.id
    inner join rs_cor_city city on city.id = jpl.city_fk
    inner join rs_organization_detail od on od.id = jp.id

    where DAY(posting_date) = @start_date
    GROUP BY jp.id, city.name, ,CONVERT(varchar(12), jp.posting_date, 103)
    order by no_of_posts Desc 
 END
```

in Sql Server `NULL` is an `UNKNOWN Value` so you really cant Compare an Unknown value to anything, When Checking for NULLs in SQL Server you should use `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`, Comparison operators (<, >, <>, <=, >=) dont work with NULL values

Comment: its still same...nothing changed :(